# Geodesics Through a Singularity

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, geodesic, general-relativity

A **singularity** on a manifold with metric is defined to be a point at which some geodesic cannot be continued through. For example in Schwarzchild spacetime, $r=0$ defines such a point.

Is it the case that *any* geodesic which hits a singularity cannot be continued past it? This is obviously true for the Schwarzchild solution. However I worry that perhaps that's just an artifact of the symmetry of the situation. There's nothing in the definition of a singularity that refers to an arbitrary geodesic through that point.

I've tried to think about this myself, but I'm not sure I have the requisite differential geometry to solve it. I can't see how (say) the Hopf-Rinow theorem, or any related results would help!

It would be great to get a mathematician's perspective on this question. Apologies if the solution if obvious and I'm just missing something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider product spaces:

For example let $C$ be a two dimensional cone with a singularity at the tip, denoted p. If you consider the product space $\mathbb R \times C$ equipped with the product metric (where $\mathbb R$ carries the standard metric) the point $(0,p)$ will be singular but for example the geodesic $t \mapsto (t,p)$ crosses it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer wspin. However I don't see how your examples are manifolds. I'm particularly trying to see whether there's an example which is a manifold and has this property.

Comment: You are right, my second example is of course a manifold with boundary, thatfor i erased that one. However, the first one works: Take $C$ to be $\mathbb R^2$ equipped with the metric $dr^2 + 1/2r^2d\theta^2$, where $(r,t)$ are polar coordinates of $\mathbb R^2$. Then $\mathbb R \times C \cong \mathbb R^3$, so it is a manifold. If you like you can also take $\mathbb R \times S$, where $S$ is the Schwarzschild spacetime.

Comment: Okay - but in that case isn't your metric singular at the tip of the cone? In which case I'm not sure that you can still talk about geodesics... Or am I missing something? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If a (pseudo) riemannian metric is not singular in $p$ you can extend any geodesic ending in $p$ for some time through $p$ since geodesics with a given initial direction always exist for some time. Thus if you can not extend some geodesic over a given point this point must be a singularity of the metric. The Schwarzschild metric for instance is singular at the tip.

Answer (score 2):

A metric in the plane with a conical singularity at say the origin with total angle $>2\pi$ around it illustrates the point well.  The issue is the non-uniqueness of the continuation of the geodesic hitting the origin.  Any continuation that forms an angle of $\geq\pi$ on "both sides" can legitimately be considered a geodesic (as far as locally minimizing properties are concerned, for example).

Comment: Hi user72694, I'm not sure I really understand your example. Maybe you could be a bit more specific. In particular I think I'm struggling on the whole concept of singularity, so perhaps you could make clear exactly what you mean by it here?

Comment: @EdwardHughes, I am not sure what babkground you are coming from exactly, but here is a try. First of all there is the usual cone in Euclidean 3-space, such as the cone over a circle.  If you measure the total angle around the singular vertex this will come out to less than $2\pi$, and the "flatter" the cone gets, the closer to $2\pi$ will be the total angle measured around the singularity. Speaking abstractly, there is nothing that prevents us from considering a singularity with total angle $>2\pi$. One way of doing this is to consider the universal cover of $R^2\setminus\{0\}$ and...

Comment: ...identifying it by a rotation by a suitable $\alpha>2\pi$. The resulting surface will not be imbeddable in Euclidean 3-space. Are you with me so far?